# No module named 'pandas.io'; 'pandas' is not a package

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Im on macOS10.13.6, installed python3 via brew and pandas via pip.

I can't import

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

in the python3 shell or in VS Code and Sublime... I'm getting this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
  File "/Users/flw/dev/csv_transform/pandas.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io'; 'pandas' is not a package
```

which python3 says:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

pip3 install pandas:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)
```

print (sys.path):

```
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/flw/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: which OS are you using? and how did you run the script?

Comment: macOS10.13.6 High Sierra. Runned it in terminal via "python3 script.py"

Comment: which pandas version are you using? can you try upgrading pandas `pip install -U pandas`

Comment: it's not working :/ Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.24.1)

Comment: is `import pandas` working?

Comment: yes just import pandas is working. But not json_normalize...

Comment: it works now also in the python shell, but in the editor i still getting the error: No name 'io' in module 'pandas', Unable to import 'pandas.io.json'

Comment: which python version is the editor using?

Comment: using Version Python 3.7.2

Comment: what do you get when you run the following `import pandas; pandas.__version__`

Comment: then i get AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: sorry i must correct my answer, getting: ImportError: bad magic number in 'pandas': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Comment: wow thank you, got it :) with this -> https://tutorials.technology/solved_errors/13-ImportError-bad-magic-number-in-x03-xf3.html

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked out

Found the error with

```
python3 -c "import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)
```

this command throw the error

```
ImportError: bad magic number in 'pandas': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

Then i fixed it with

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

doing a clean on the pyc files...